# Unable to set ViewModel property when bound to UWP ComboBox

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

In a UWP/Template10 app we have a ComboBox bound to a ViewModel property. The value of the ViewModel property is set in OnNavigatedToAsync. If we remove the ComboBox binding the property in the ViewModel is set appropriately. But if the ComboBox is bound to the property, the ViewModel property remains null.

The XAML looks like this

```
<ComboBox 
    Name="JobTypeComboBox" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind JobViewModel.JobTypes}" 
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind JobViewModel.JobType,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ChangeTypeConverter}}"/>
```

The ViewModel looks like this

```
JobType _JobType = default(JobType);
public JobType JobType { get { return _JobType; } set { Set(ref _JobType, value); } }
public ObservableCollection<JobType> JobTypes = new ObservableCollection<JobType>(JobTypeService.GetJobTypes());

public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
    {
            this.JobType = job.JobType;
```

**EDIT 1:** The converter looks like this

```
public class ChangeTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (targetType.IsConstructedGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
        }

        if (value == null && targetType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);

        if (targetType.IsInstanceOfType(value))
            return value;

        return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return Convert(value, targetType, parameter, language);
    }
}
```

In the execution of the line `this.JobType = job.JobType;` there are 6 calls to the converter:

Convert is called with the correct value for JobType and returns the correct value.

ConvertBack is called with value = null and returns null;

Convert is called with value = null and returns null;

Convert is called with value = null and returns null;

ConvertBack is called with value = null and returns null;

Convert is called with value = null and returns null;

So it looks like the binding is bouncing the value back to ConvertBack as null.

`Job.JobType` is returned correctly. If the binding is removed from `JobTypeComboBox`, `this.jobType` is set correctly. When the binding is added to `JobTypeComboBox`, `this.JobType` remains null.

How do I set the value of `this.jobType` when `JobTypeComboBox` is bound to it?

Comment: 1. is the job.JobType element from the collection binded to ItemsSource? Hope you know it is set to Mode=OneTime only by default? 2. what about ChangeTypeConverter? have you tried to get into it and see what happens there?

Comment: @RTDev The ItemsSource for JobTypeComboBox is ObservableCollection<JobType> JobTypes. Mode=TwoWay.  job.JobType is not bound to the ItemsSource. JobTypeComboBox is bound to the ItemSource. ChangeTypeConverter is from Template10. It returns the target type of the sender. If I remove ChangeTypeConverter from the binding job.JobType is set correctly. I do need ChangeTypeConverter as JobTypeComboBox is bound to JobType not a string.

Comment: if I understand you correctly - the problem is with your converter. Try to change it with this fake (it is doing no more than just pretending to be covnerterter that do anything but It does not, but makes xaml compile): public class ObjectToObject : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {            
            return value;
        }
    
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }

Comment: @RTDev I implemented `ObjectToObjectConverter` and `JobTypeComboBox SelectedItem="{x:Bind JobViewModel.JobType,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ObjectToObjectConverter}}` but in the ViewModel `this.JobType` is still null

Comment: don't use x:Bind with the JobType.... Give it a whirl... and drop the converter

Comment: Thank you @mvermef if I change from x:Bind to Binding and drop the converter I am able to set the property but the ComboBox doesn't show the property as the SelectedItem.

Comment: create very simple runnable piece of code that we can run if you may please, that could help us to reproduce issue and find out what is still wrong

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @RTDev  but I am unable to post a working solution as it requires Template10. I have copied the T10 converter into my solution and stepped through it. I have edited my post to include the converter and the results of stepping through.

Comment: Where does  this statement `this.JobType = job.JobType;` get the lower case variable `job`.  With my previous comment above, what does it show instead of the "JobType"

Comment: @mvermef `job` is passed in as a parameter to `OnNavigatedToAsync` and `job.JobType` is already populated when it is passed in. `JobTypes` is populated in the ViewModel constructor so there shouldn't be a race condition should there? I have also checked that `job.JobType` is in `JobTypes` before `this.JobType` is set.

Comment: @mvermef  ooops forgot to answer your question. Nothing shows in the ComboBox as SelectedItem but the list of ComboBoxItems is populated correctly and selecting from the list sets the property correctly.

Comment: I don't think you need a converter.

Comment: The problem was that JobTypes was not the itemssource for the ComboBox. The itemssource was a lookup list. When I set the ViewModel.JobType to the selected item in the lookup list all was tickety boo. My apologies for omitting significant information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using this view-model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ComboBoxItem = ComboBoxItems.First();
    }

    string _ComboBoxItem = default(string);
    public string ComboBoxItem { get { return _ComboBoxItem; } set { Set(ref _ComboBoxItem, value); } }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" });
}
```

And this XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="testComboBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="parameterResizer"
            RelativePanel.Below="stateTextBox"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<TextBlock x:Name="testTextBlock"
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="parameterResizer"
            RelativePanel.Below="testComboBox"
            Text="{Binding ComboBoxItem}" />
```

I got this to happen:

[image]

Thanks for using Template 10 - though I think this has nothing to do with T10. :-)

Comment: Setting the value in `OnNavigatedToAsync` works, too.